# How to delete a row from a dataframe if a value in the index is NaN or blank string

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I am new to python and wondering if there is a simple way to fix my problem below:
I would like to remove an entire row from the dataframe if the index is 'NaN'. I have tried the following

```
df.dropna(inplace=True,subset=[df.index.values])
```

I know how to do this if I want to only look for NaN values in any other column, but I am not sure how to do it for the index values. Thanks much!

Comment: you can replace the empty string with `np.nan` and apply `dropna`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = df[df.index.notnull()]
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks @nimbous, please upvote my question if possible as I am desperate for my first 15 reputation points

Answer (score 1):

maybe try this:

```
df = df.dropna(how='all')
print(df)
```

Comment: I think this would work if i was willing to let it drop all of my NaN values that existed across the entire dataframe, but how could I isolate the subset of index values to be considered for the Nan criteria in order to delete the row? does that make sense? Trying to do my best to describe it lol

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26744800)

Comment: @aribeiro yeah I tried to add a comment but it was not possible! Nice, thanks for the tip!